# Making a box appear infront of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to place a little box in front of my html page. And inside that box I want two buttons, that will execute an command or just start something when press on. If you press on a button or outside the box the box will disappear like in picture 2.

[image: PICTURE 1:]

[image: PICTURE 2:]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `confirm()` box using JavaScript:

**Example:**

```
var r=confirm("Press a button");
if (r==true)
  {
  x="You pressed OK!";
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }
```

Comment: Still how do I place it infront of my page?

Comment: You'd set it to be on page load and it would appear as soon as the page is loaded, maybe you could disable all other elements on the page being used unless the user selects 'yes' for example

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a modal dialog or a lightbox. I recommend using one of the tons of javascript and jQuery modal plugins. For example:

- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals
- http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Or ColorBox as Tom suggested, or any other of tons.

Or something like `<body onload="if (confirm('Do you want to start the music?')) startMusic();">…`

Answer (score 1):

[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) can do what you want. You 'll need to make `<div>` element with your buttons and point fancybox to that div.

Answer (score 1):

you are going to need a dialog , a plug-in would be the best , as for getting it to disappear if you click outside the box , plugins sometimes handle this .  jQuery's modal-dialog will lock the screen outside the box .  If you want to do this on your own , you would make a div that has 100% width and 100% height , and you could set .1 for opacity so you could see through it.  Then on click of the div you would hide the overlay div and hid the dialog div as well.  For setting the dialog in front , the plugin would handle this , but you do this by setting the z-index higher then any other `z-index` on the page.

Then picture of your example - with yes or no buttons .  THat is not something that you typically want the user to be able to click outside and have disappear.  The disappearing is usually for pictures.   A yes- no normally would lock the screen and wait for a response.  But you can use any type of dialog you'd like i guess

Answer (score 0):

Try using colorbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox, specifically the inline html.

Set the background-color and add your buttons